# How to concatenate two tables with matched columns into a single view

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables in a Microsoft Access 2007 database.

One of them has columns "name 1  & name 2" with 2000 records. The other table has more information: it has two columns named "code1 & code2" with 3000 records. Each name has a code means that every name has a code stored in the second table in the column code 1.

I want to make one table or query that shows me name 1 & name 2 with their specific code1 & code 2 from the second table .

**And it must have only 2000 records**

example :

tabel 1 :

```
name-1      name-2
-----------------------------
Abacavir    Digoxin
Amprenavir  Aspirin
```

tabel 2 :

```
code-1   drug1       
----------------
xy1      Abacavir 
xy2      Digoxin    
yxr1     Amprenavir 
uyv2     Aspirin
```

sample output :

```
name-1     code-1  name-2  code-2
-----------------------------------------
Abacavir   xy1     Digoxin  xy2
```

Comment: It would help if you [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19884085/edit) your question to show us some representative sample data: [Table1], [Table2], and the desired result. In particular, you could illustrate why there might be more than one match in [Table2] for a given record in [Table1], and which value from [Table2] you want to retrieve, and why.

Comment: i have edited it please see it again if you can help me

Comment: Is the issue that you have the same name1 value twice in table2 and you want both code1 values together as a single field ? Your sample data is still mostly illegible, I'm not sure where to start except to make random guesses as to what you're asking for.

Comment: no its not like what you understand ..
i have 2 tabels .. one has 2000 record , the other has 3000 
the second table has code for each name in the first table 
that is called "drug" in tabel 2 
i want only the 2000 and their codes from table2 to show up

Answer (score 0):

This table structure is poorly designed but I'll assume you are stuck with it.  You have to create a query that joins Table2 twice... once for each of the relationships you are linking by.  In my test I created an access db and named my tables simple Table1 and Table2 so you may need to alter this query slightly to match your table/column names.

```
SELECT Table1.name1, Table2a.code1, Table1.name2, Table2b.code1
FROM (Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 AS Table2b ON Table1.name2 = Table2b.drug1) LEFT JOIN Table2 AS Table2a ON Table1.name1 = Table2a.drug1;
```

Comment: it doesnt work :'( 
it gives me  about 4000 records WITH THE FIRST ROW REPEATED !!

Comment: All I can say is that given the data you supplied (which wasn't much) it worked.  Perhaps you have repeated records in table2 that are causing duplicates?  If so, adding DISTINCT after the SELECT keyword might take care of it but without a better window into your data I can't begin to guess beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

The fact you have 2K in the first and 3K in the second is a clue.  Try adding the 'Distinct' key in your SQL statement:
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.name1, Table2a.code1, Table1.name2, Table2b.code1
FROM (Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 AS Table2b ON Table1.name2 = Table2b.drug1) LEFT JOIN Table2 AS Table2a ON Table1.name1 = Table2a.drug1;

Otherwise I think Frank nailed it.